# Explain why variables in my function are not related to variables in my script in Python 2

Tags: python-2.7

I am doing learn Python the hard way. I have read, and believe I understand how everything works in this example, but the author notes this sentence I cannot wrap my head around.

"There is one tiny point that you might not have realized, which we'll reinforce right now. The variables in your function are not connected to the variables in your script. Here's an exercise to get you thinking about this:"

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex19.html

I have done all the typing, study exercises etc, and have looked at this example for at least an hour. I understand all the components, but think I am missing the gist of the exercise. I may know what he means on some level.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more precise about what you're asking. What exactly is unclear? What do you think it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the function (simplified a bit from your example to get to the point) :

```
def cheese(cheese_count):
    print "You have %d cheeses!" % cheese_count
```

In this context `cheese_count` is the argument of the function. It is declared in the function signature, and then used in the function body. When you pass a value to your function this value replaces `cheese_count` in the body of the function. So if I call this function as :

```
cheese(10)
```

it will be equivalent to :

```
"You have %d cheeses!" % 10
```

which is in turn equivalent to :

```
"You have 10 cheeses!"
```

To resume, *in the context of this function*, `cheese_count = 10`. So what about outside of the context of this function ?

```
def cheese(cheese_count):
    print "You have %d cheeses!" % cheese_count

cheese_count = 20
print cheese(10)
```

Here, I assign `20` to `cheese_count` before calling my `cheese` function. If you try to run this code, you will see it prints `You have 10 cheeses!`. So obviously, the `cheese_count` variable outside of the function is not the same variable as the `cheese_count` inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that your function makes a copy of those variables

For example if you have

```
def cheese(cheese_count):
  cheese_count = 10

global_cheese_count = 100
cheese(global_cheese_count)
print (global_cheese_count)
```

It will print 100 and not 10, even if you set it in your function. Note that this is valid for "primitive types" such as numbers and strings but not objects such as arrays, dictionaries and other kinds of objects.

```
def cheese(cheese_count):
  cheese_count[0] = 10

global_cheese_count = [ 100 ]
cheese(global_cheese_count)
print (global_cheese_count)
```

This will print 10